# My list of objects is not updating dynamically on method get

Tags: angularjs

I made an interface for the user so he can create, add, remove and edit a product. The product has a description and a type that the user can specify when he creates the product, the problem is that, when the user creates the product or edit it, the list that lists the products is not updating with the new product dynamically.

```
<div>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showModalEdit()">
    New Product
  </md-button>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Description</b></td>
          <td><b>Type</b></td>
          <td align="center"><b>Editar</b></td>
          <td align="center"><b>Excluir</b></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
          <td>{{product.description}}</td>
          <td>{{product.type.description}}</td>
          <td align="center">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="btnEditProduct(product)"></span>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="showConfirm(product._id)"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the New Product button, a modal appears so he can write the description and the product type, after that, he clicks on the Create button that calls a function that pass the product object so it can be saved on the database:

```
<md-button ng-click="addProduct(product)">
  Create
</md-button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showModalEdit = function() {
  var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  && $scope.customFullscreen;
  $mdDialog.show({
    //clickOutsideToClose: true,
    controller: DialogProduct,
    scope: $scope,
    templateUrl: '../../views/editproduct.html',
    plain: true,
    fullscreen: useFullScreen
  }).then(function(answer) {
    console.log('fechou a modal', $scope.product)
  }, function closeModalEdit() {
    console.log('fechou a modal', $scope.product)
  });
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
  }, function(wantsFullScreen) {
    $scope.customFullscreen = (wantsFullScreen === true);
  });
};

$scope.addProduct = function(newProduct) {
  //This service is just returning the type ID of the product that was set before
  newProduct.type = serviceShareProductType.get();
  serviceProduct.save(newProduct, function(data){
    $scope.getProducts();
    $mdDialog.hide();
  }, function(err){
  });
}

$scope.getProducts = function() {
  serviceProduct.query(function(data) {
    $scope.products = data.value;
    console.log(data);
  },function(err){
  });
}
```

Service:

```
get: function (idproduct, success, error) {
  $http.get(ipServer+'product/'+idproduct).success(success).error(error);
}
```

Everything is working just fine, if I console.log(the list of products) the new product that the user just created is there with the other products, but the user have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Where you add new `newProduct` in `products` array?

Comment: When and where are doing this console.log(list of products) ? We need more information...

Comment: Stepan, the newProduct is added to the products array when I call the get funtion, it returns me all the products from the database, I added the code to the question so you can see it: $scope.getProducts.

Comment: Gustavo, I'm doing the console.log inside the controller right before i call the get function

Comment: Gustavo, I added it to the question so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `getProducts()` method on success of save HTTP request and update   `products` array with `getProducts()`.

Comment: I made the callback with the success from the service and it didn't work and I'm already calling getProducts() to update the products array.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to call `$scope.$apply()` when you call the function that pass the product object. this article was a lot of help to me.
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: may19c19, I have tried it but I keep getting this error: $digest already in progress, I have read about the digest and tried to verify when it is executing, and it doesn't update anything.